# owlcarousel2 event.item.index - неправильно подсчитывает при включении loop

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Всем привет, нужна ваша помощь !

У меня **event.item.index** некорректно подсчитывает при включении **loop: true** где я мог допустить ошибку !?

Подскажите пожалуйста !

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  const headerSlider = $("#headerSlider");

  headerSlider.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $('.slide-controls-number__active').text(event.item.index + 1)
    $('.slide-controls-number__total').text(event.item.count)
  });

  headerSlider.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    dots: false,
    autoplayTimeout: 2000,
    autoplay: true
  });

  headerSlider.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $('.slide-controls-number__active').text(event.item.index + 1)
    $('.slide-controls-number__total').text(event.item.count)
  });

});
```

```css
#headerSlider {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#headerSlider,
.slide-controls-number {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.theme.green.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div id="headerSlider" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="slide-item">
    <div class="slide-item__img">Test 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item">
    <div class="slide-item__img">Test 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item">
    <div class="slide-item__img">Test 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item">
    <div class="slide-item__img">Test 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item">
    <div class="slide-item__img">Test 5</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide-controls-number">
  <span class="slide-controls-number__active">1</span>
  <span class="slide-controls-number__from">/</span>
  <span class="slide-controls-number__total">5</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему owl-carousel так считает слайды, не подскажу, но решение проблемы довольно простое - вместо event.item.index + 1 пишете event.item.index - 2 (и initialized.owl.carousel без надобности):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  const headerSlider = $("#headerSlider");

  headerSlider.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    dots: false,
    autoplayTimeout: 2000,
    autoplay: true
  });

  headerSlider.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $('.slide-controls-number__active').text(event.item.index - 2)
    $('.slide-controls-number__total').text(event.item.count)
  });

});
```

```css
#headerSlider {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#headerSlider,
.slide-controls-number {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.theme.green.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div id="headerSlider" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="slide-item">
    <div class="slide-item__img">Test 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item">
    <div class="slide-item__img">Test 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item">
    <div class="slide-item__img">Test 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item">
    <div class="slide-item__img">Test 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item">
    <div class="slide-item__img">Test 5</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide-controls-number">
  <span class="slide-controls-number__active">1</span>
  <span class="slide-controls-number__from">/</span>
  <span class="slide-controls-number__total">5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Все отлично заработало, спасибо Вам ! Только я вот один один баг нашел, при перелистываний вручную слайд уход на  6 / 5 ((